# Rspec route matching - same expected vs actual, yet error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

> 1) ExampleController routes for Example routes
>         Failure/Error: expect( post: '/api/application').to route_to( format: 'json', action: 'create_application', controller: 'example')
>           The recognized options <{"format"=>"json", "action"=>"create_application", "controller"=>"example"}> did not
>   match <{"format"=>"json", "action"=>"create_application",
>   "controller"=>"example"}>,
>
> difference:.
>
> <{"format"=>"json", "action"=>"create_application",
>   "controller"=>"example"}>
>
> expected but was
>
> <{"format"=>"json", "action"=>"create_application",
>   "controller"=>"example"}>.

Am I missing something here? I feel as if expected and actual are the same.

@charles

routes.rb:

```
scope '/api', :defaults => { format: 'json' } do
  resource :application, only:[] do
    post :create, to: 'example#create_application'
  end
end
```

rake routes:

> application POST /api/application(.:format) example#create_application
>   {:format=>"json"}

Working now with:

```
describe "routes for Example" do   
  it "routes" do
    expect( post: '/api/application').to route_to( "example#create_application", :format=>"json" )   
  end 
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant section in your routes file and the relevant section when running rake routes?

Comment: Added above. Thanks Charles.

Comment: Does it pass if you change to `expect( post: '/api/application.json')`?

Comment: That would also be my best guess.

Answer (score 1):

I was Having same issue.

You just need to add hash in route_to function like.

```
it 'routes to /v1/auth to user_token#create' do
  expect(:post => '/v1/users/auth.json').to route_to({"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"v1/sessions", "action"=>"create"})
end
```

Like above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

My **controller** was: `api/v1/users`

My **route** was defined this was:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end
  end
end
```

And I was defining my **spec route** this way:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(get: "api/v1/users").to route_to(controller: :api/v1/users, action: :index)
    end
  end
end
```

But each time I ran into the error:

> The recognized options <{"format"=>"json", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"api/v1/users"}> did not match <{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"api/v1/users"}>

**Here's how I fixed it:**

I simply modified the **spec route** from this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(get: "api/v1/users").to route_to(controller: :api/v1/users, action: :index)
    end
  end
end
```

to this:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(get: "api/v1/users").to route_to(format: :json, controller: "api/v1/users", action: "index")
    end
  end
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**